# How do I get list of all users in TFS 2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, tfs

I am using Team Foundation Server (TFS) 2013 and Visual studio 2012. I need a list of all the user in TFS.

Is there any way to get all the users in TFS using C#?

Comment: Thank you John. I want to see the list in code. Not in UI. If you have sample code can you share?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Get the users list from TFS 2010, you can try use the TFS API, please refer to the following code snippet:

```
TfsTeamProjectCollection tfs = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("url"));
tfs.EnsureAuthenticated();

IGroupSecurityService gss = tfs.GetService<IGroupSecurityService>();

Identity SIDS = gss.ReadIdentity(SearchFactor.AccountName, "Project Collection Valid Users", QueryMembership.Expanded);

Identity[] UserId = gss.ReadIdentities(SearchFactor.Sid, SIDS.Members, QueryMembership.None);

foreach (Identity user in UserId)
{
    Console.WriteLine(user.AccountName);
    Console.WriteLine(user.DisplayName);
}
```

Please try this code, above code is working in VS2010 & VS2013. Let me know if you have any questions.

More information in **[this link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/1575bc23-55cf-48d8-9041-9d5910d1195b/getting-list-of-tfs-2010-all-users)**