# Is there a TFS extension SDK API or REST API call to get all users from TFS 2017?

Tags: tfs

I have a TFS extension that needs to get a list of all users in TFS 2017. Is there an API call for this? The closest thing I've been able to find is the [CoreHttpClient.getTeamMembers()](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/reference/client/api/tfs/core/restclient/corehttpclient2_2#method_getTeamMembers) REST client call. But I'm looking for something that returns a list of all user identities.

Google searches have yielded some results for older versions of TFS that don't appear applicable to TFS 2017.

*Note 1: this is for an on-site hosted TFS instance, not VSTS.*

*Note 2: I'm looking for a way to call this API from the frontend JavaScript code of the TFS extension.*

Thanks!

**UPDATE 06/29/2017:** See Patrick's comment in his answer. Apparently there's no REST API that's callable from the TFS extension frontend at the moment.

Answer (score 3):

There is no Rest API could do this for now. You have to use old client API with **[ReadIdentities](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff738489(v=vs.120).aspx)** method. This also works on TFS2017. Sample code:

```
TfsTeamProjectCollection tfs = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("url"));
tfs.EnsureAuthenticated();

IGroupSecurityService gss = tfs.GetService<IGroupSecurityService>();

Identity SIDS = gss.ReadIdentity(SearchFactor.AccountName, "Project Collection Valid Users", QueryMembership.Expanded);

Identity[] UserId = gss.ReadIdentities(SearchFactor.Sid, SIDS.Members, QueryMembership.None);

foreach (Identity user in UserId)
{
    Console.WriteLine(user.AccountName);
    Console.WriteLine(user.DisplayName);
}
```

More details please refer [How do I get list of all users in TFS 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30639288/how-do-i-get-list-of-all-users-in-tfs-2013) and there is also many others in google.

It's using [.NET client libraries for TFS](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/get-started/client-libraries/dotnet), you could use those method by importing the nuget package into your Visual Studio projects. This is also work with TFS2017.

Comment: I need to make this call from within a TFS extension; is it possible to call that API from within the frontend JavaScript code? I've added an explanatory note to my question to clarify. Thanks for your time!

Comment: The only thing stopping me from accepting this answer is due to me needing to call the API from within the frontend JavaScript code :(

Comment: Hi @broAhmed, after go through more info and API. Unfortunately, it's still not able to do this with the frontend JavaScript code fro now:(. You could do this with client API, Powershell, querying database, just not Rest API . You could add a [uservocie](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services), TFS PM will kindly review your suggestion.

Comment: Bummer, but I appreciate the followup. Thanks again for your time!