# Get all members/users from TFS via REST API

Tags: c#, tfs

I tried to get all members/users of TFS with the REST API and the [.NET client libraries](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/vsts/integrate/concepts/dotnet-client-libraries?view=vsts).

It works, but I get a maximum number of 50 identitys. Does anyone know, how I get all users, not only 50? (I prefer avoiding to use the old API, how it is suggested in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44666525/is-there-an-sdk-api-or-rest-api-call-to-get-all-users-from-tfs-2017))

Here is my code:

```
    VssCredentials credentials = new VssCredentials();
    VssConnection connection = new VssConnection(new Uri(url), credentials);

    IdentityMruHttpClient identityMruHttpClient = connection.GetClient<IdentityMruHttpClient>();
    List<IdentityRef> members = identityMruHttpClient.GetIdentityMruAsync(ProjectName).Result;
```

Comment: You said "I prefer avoiding to use the old API" but in your code you use it... so do you want to do it with REST API or with old TFS API like your code?

Comment: Are you sure? However, I want to use the REST API using this package (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a REST API [User Entitlements - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/rest/api/vsts/memberentitlementmanagement/user%20entitlements/list?view=vsts-rest-4.1) which can retrieve the user list from VSTS (`Visual Studio Team Services`), but it's only available for VSTS.

There isn't such a REST API to retrieve the user list from **on-premise** TFS (TFS 2017 in your scenario).

So, for now you can use the [client API](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client/) you mentioned above to retrieve the user list. Tested on my side, I can retrieve all the identities (more than 50 ) with below code:

You can also check the user list from `userlist.txt` file which under `..\..\ \bin\Debug\`

```
using System;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Common;
using System.Linq;
using System.IO;

namespace Getuserlist

{

    class Program

    {
        static void Main(string[] args)

        {

            TfsConfigurationServer tcs = new TfsConfigurationServer(new Uri("http://server:8080/tfs"));

            IIdentityManagementService ims = tcs.GetService<IIdentityManagementService>();

            TeamFoundationIdentity tfi = ims.ReadIdentity(IdentitySearchFactor.AccountName, "Project Collection Valid Users", MembershipQuery.Expanded, ReadIdentityOptions.None);

            TeamFoundationIdentity[] ids = ims.ReadIdentities(tfi.Members, MembershipQuery.None, ReadIdentityOptions.None);

            using (StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter("userlist.txt"))

                foreach (TeamFoundationIdentity id in ids)

                {
                    if (id.Descriptor.IdentityType == "System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity")

                    { Console.WriteLine(id.DisplayName); }
                    //{ Console.WriteLine(id.UniqueName); }

                    file.WriteLine("[{0}]", id.DisplayName);
                }

            var count = ids.Count(x => ids.Contains(x));
            Console.WriteLine(count);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It works perfectly. Nevertheless I am still wondering why I get only 50 users with my code.