# Fetch user identities from TFS using C# REST API

Tags: rest, azure-devops, tfs

In OM API as we used to fetch user identities and we can put search on multiple values for example:
when we set IdentitySearchFilter = IdentitySearchFilter.DisplayName we were able to give multiple user display names to fetch multiple users, how can we achieve this in C# REST API, because it is accepting only one display name to fetch its user?

```
IdentitiesCollection identities =
                    identityHttpClient.ReadIdentitiesAsync(IdentitySearchFilter.DisplayName, displayName[0]).Result;
```

I have a list of displayNames to fetch users in one call to TFS.

Comment: Any update to the issue?

Comment: No updates yet, I think they have not done implementation of this method in REST API.

Answer (score 0):

Below code will help you to fetch all the user list:

```
foreach(var displayName in displayNames)
{
    var result = await client.ReadIdentitiesAsync(IdentitySearchFilter.DisplayName, displayName).Result;
}
```

OR

```
foreach(var displayName in displayNames)
{
    IdentitiesCollection identities = identityHttpClient.ReadIdentitiesAsync(IdentitySearchFilter.DisplayName, displayName).Result;
}
```

Refer this similar [SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51245425/get-all-members-users-from-tfs-via-rest-api) and [MSFT documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/graph/users/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) to get all the users in a given scope and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/memberentitlementmanagement/members/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) is for getting direct members in a group.

Comment: I don't want to do multiple calls to the server as it affects on performance of application.